# How to save custom object data in salesforce with Apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, controller

Following is my custom object controller in Apex. I think it will work fine with the data coming from VF page. But what for the variable `datesFromCalendar` which contains the contents of JS array. How to save this variable in salesforce?

```
public with sharing class EventsPageController {
    public Event__c Event {get; private set;}
    public String datesFromCalendar {get; set;}
    public pagereference saveData(){
        System.debug(datesFromCalendar);
        try {
            upsert(Event);
        } catch(System.DMLException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }
        // After Save, navigate to the default view page:
        return (new ApexPages.StandardController(Event)).view();
    }
}
```

Following is the VF code.

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageMessages id="errors"/>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Event Scheduler" mode="edit">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Event Detail" mode="edit" id="criteria">
        <apex:inputField id="eventType" value="{!Event.Event_Type__c}" required="true"/>
        <select name="occurrence" id="occurrence">
            <option>Select Occurrence</option>
            <option value="0">One Time</option>
            <option value="7">Weekly</option>
            <option value="30">Monthly</option>
            <option value="15">Bi-Monthly</option>
        </select>

    <input type="text" name="event_start_date" id="from" placeholder="On or after" style="height:20px; width:200px;"/>
    <input type="text" name="event_end_date" id="to" placeholder="On or before" style="height:20px; width:200px;"/>
    <apex:inputField id="eventDescription" value="{!Event.Event_Description__c}"/>
    <apex:inputField id="maxAttendees" value="{!Event.Maximum_Attendees__c}" required="true"/>
    <apex:inputField id="progName" value="{!Event.Program_Name__c}" required="true"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Calendar" id="calendarBlock">
    <div align="right">
        <select id="selectedDates" style="visibility:hidden"></select>
        <button id="saveCalendar"><span>Save Calendar</span></button>
        <apex:inputHidden value="{!datesFromCalendar}" id="hiddenDatesCollector"/>
        <apex:actionFunction name="passDatesToController" action="{!saveData}" rerender="hiddenDatesCollector"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <apex:commandButton id="saveEventBtn" value="Save Event" onclick="sendSelectedDates(); return false;"/>
    </div>
    <div id="myCalendar"></div>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: Could you add the VisualForce page to your question, which will help people figure out what you are asking.

Comment: @BarCotter VF code is added in the question. plz have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe you will just have to do this:

```
try {
   Event.Your_Field__c = datesFromCalendar;
   upsert(Event);
} catch(System.DMLException e) {
   ApexPages.addMessages(e);
   return null;
}
```

So just before doing that upsert, you have to set the field on the Event object. Unless the data in the JS Array is different and you want to split the various values from it? Or the user can pick multiple dates?

I made this assumption as you declared the variable `datesFromCalendar` as a String.

**UPDATE**

If you know there will always be a comma between the dates you could use the Split method on the String class. You will still keep the dates in the String variable and do this:

```
List<String> listOfDates = datesFromCalendar.split(',');
```

Then you can easily do a for loop on the list. You could also parse the String in to a DateTime data type by using on each date after the split this code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.parse( Your individual date here );
```

Comment: Thanks Mihai for your answer. Here is the contents of `datesFromCalendar` 
_[5]|DEBUG|01/13/2015,01/20/2015,01/27/2015,02/03/2015,02/10/2015,02/17/2015,02/24/2015,03/03/2015,03/10/2015,03/17/2015,03/24/2015,03/31/2015,04/07/2015,04/14/2015,04/21/2015,06/10/2015_
 Also please tell me what will be the right type to save these values in the object? Once these dates will be saved. I have to get back them from salesforce and show them on the calendar for each Event. Any ideas please. Thanks.

Comment: Updated my answer. I'm not really to sure on the second requirement. You need to create one Event per date ? I see you have an upsert so are you trying to say that if an Event already exists do not try and create it?

Comment: There is an Event__c object in salesforce. And not a single record exists yet. Records will be created through the above VF page and the controller. I'm not sure if I need to take care of the Id for each record. as I created an Id field in the object at the time of its creation which is Autonumber. I'll be thankful if you can guide me a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Superman,

You have a couple options, you could store those all in a Text Area (long) or if you don't want to actually store the dates, you could recalculate them in your controller and pass them to your calendar. Since you know the start date, end date and frequency it is up to you. Your trade off will be space/speed.  If it were me I would probably recalculate the dates, but not sure on the scope of your application.

You will need to then convert or create the array to pass back to your calendar in the format your calendar needs for display. If you provide the calendar you would like to use we could probably provide you with additional help.

Comment: In my case I provide user with a calendar on which user can select dates and along with couple of other fields, I'm trying to save it in salesforce. And yes I have created a Text Area(long) on the object to hold these dates. However these dates are not for the presentational purpose other than on the calendar. So I didn't add this Text Area on layout. Somehow there are multiple issues going on. I'm not even able to save the fields. :) Its my first ever project and encounter with VF and Apex.

Comment: In that case try simplify your process so that you get the save function working.  Try changing your command button to: <apex:commandButton value="Save Event" action="{!saveData}" />  Possibly take a look at a resource that can go through an example with you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Z4KTh1woCU

Comment: I'm using the same commandButton to send the JS variable value. Is that Ok? Note: I can't have an extra button to send the JS variable value. Any suggestion?

Comment: Take a look at the following thread, it should help you get where you need to be. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000Ac7ZIAS